# How extract non-unique columns in another table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table `sample_source` which contains 4 columns:

```
---------------------------------------------------
|id  | name | target_value | another_target_value |
===================================================
|1   | John |  'wow'       |   'value'            |
---------------------------------------------------
|2   | Liza |  'wow'       |   'value'            |
---------------------------------------------------
|3   | Mark |  'awesome'   |   'value'            |
---------------------------------------------------
|4   |Daniel|  'awesome'   |   'value'            |
---------------------------------------------------
```

And i wanna extract `target_value`  and `another_target_value` to table `values`(with duplicating)

Trying write something like

```
with cte as (insert into values(target_value, another_target_value)
             select target_value, another_target_value from sample_source t1
             returning id, t1.id as source_id)
update 
    sample_source
set
    value_id = cte.id
where
    sample_source.id = cte.source_id
```

based on [this discussion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151604/how-to-split-table-into-two-tables-in-one-transaction-or-query) 
but i can't use `sample_source` table in returning clause

**UPD** Expected result:

```
sample_source
------------------------
|id  | name | value_id |
========================
|1   | John |  1       |
------------------------
|2   | Liza |  2       |
------------------------
|3   | Mark |  3       | 
------------------------
|4   |Daniel| 4        |
------------------------

values
--------------------------------------------
|id  | target_value | another_target_value |
============================================
|1   |  'wow'       |   'value'            |
--------------------------------------------
|2   |  'wow'       |   'value'            |
--------------------------------------------
|3   |  'awesome'   |   'value'            |
--------------------------------------------
|4   |  'awesome'   |   'value'            |
--------------------------------------------
```

of course i have `create`, `alter`, and other scripts, problem only with moving data

Comment: First, `values` is a reserved word in SQL, so you may want to find a different name. Second - could you share the resulting table you'd like to get. I must admit I didn't quite understand the question.

Comment: @Mureinik Updated(add result). i know about `values`, it just a sample

Comment: Maybe you could choose different *distinctive* names and values. Now, `sample_source.id=1` seems to refer to `sample_source.value_id=1 == values.id=1` And you should *really* avoid the name `values`.

Answer (score 1):

Having the duplication without the `id` is weird.  You can enumerate *afterwards* in each of the tables to do what you want:

```
with i as (
      insert into vals (target_value, another_target_value)
          select target_value, another_target_value
          from sample_source t1
          returning id, t1.id as source_id
     ),
     i2 as (
      select i.*,
             row_number() over (partition by target_value, another_target_value order by target_value) as seqnum
      from i
     )
update sample_source ss
    set value_id = i2.id
from (select ss2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by target_value, another_target_value order by target_value) as seqnum
      from sample_source ss2
     ) ss2 join
     i2
     on i2.target_value = ss2.target_value and
        i2.another_target_value = ss2.another_target_value and
        i2.seqnum = ss2.seqnum
where ss.id = ss2.id;
```